# How to proxy every HTTP request to other service in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating ASP.NET MVC controller, which would proxy requests to remote service and after response is got - resend response to the client. It works fine, but I get System.Net.WebException when remote server returns (400) Bad Request.

Is there any way how to proxy any kind of response to the client, without raising such exeptions?

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
Request.CopyTo(request);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
return new HttpWebResponseResult(response);
```

Comment: It is not a very new question but shows up high on my google search (as do all so questions). I found the following may work for me, you and others stumbling upon this question. https://gist.github.com/jkresner/3982746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All web client API provided with .NET framework are designed to send an exception everytime it sees a `4XX` or `5XX` error. If you want to override this behaviour, you have to wrap your `webRequest` or `webclient` call inside `try/catch`.

As proxying means lot of waiting, to avoid consuming too much ressource and fasten your answer, prefer defining your controller method as async and await the answer :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
var response = await Task<HttpWebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse);
return new HttpWebResponseResult(response);
```

Comment: this 'proxy' isn't going to pass through request headers, or cookies, or bodies.  may be fine for @Tomas's needs but not a good general purpose proxy approach

Comment: In my answer I just forgot the "Request.CopyTo" call. 
I don't see where it is not a good "proxy" technique. Of course a true proxy server can process better than a ASP controller but if he want's to take advantage of session, authentication or any data of its database, it's ok.